# Free performance monitoring tools for local development for Java based web-applications

Tags: open-source, java, performance-analysis, profiling

For Java based web-applications: If a developer wants to instantly get performance related feedback during local development, would anyone please recommend any free APM (application performance monitoring)/profilers that one can use for the same? Ideally, the performance feedback generated by such tools should be similar to that created by Xrebel which shows the whole request stack trace right from HTTP call down to the SQL(s) fired.

Answer (score 0):

[Jvisualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) and [Java Mission Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr002.html) come with the JDK and can be found in $JAVA_HOME/bin.  This [Oracle web page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#jconsole) has some good overview information.  Check out [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50653/server-application-monitoring/50699#50699) also.